# How to Extract value from Json Path Post Processor?

Tags: json, regex, jmeter

I need to extract **id** where **asOf** : 2016-11 for latest run.

e.g given below response of request I need to store `21aa83fe-fe1b-4447-9b2e-05e7d6cd67d3` in a variable because as of 2016 is in the last and-and the corresponding id is. Could you please tell me how to write JSON Path Post Processor Expression out of it?

```
{"id":"1fabbb02-0b7d-4bec-badd-9fe9f1c63f08","batch" {"id":"GL1600"},"asOf":"2014-06-16T00:00:00Z","version":3,"statusIdentifier":"END"},
{"id":"212fc2b5-03d6-4d76-ab6d-e9e783459120","batch":{"id":"N1400"},"asOf":"2014-06-16T00:00:00Z","version":3,"statusIdentifier":"END"},
{"id":"21aa83fe-fe1b-4447-9b2e-05e7d6cd67d3","batch":{"id":"N1500"},"asOf":"2016-11-16T00:00:00Z","version":3,"statusIdentifier":"END"},
```

Comment: can you please share the original JSON? i.e., hierarchy from its parent node so that we can provide exact answer?

Answer (score 1):

If your response is valid JSON you can use `==` filter operator like

```
$..[?(@.asOf == '2016-11-16T00:00:00Z')].id
```

References:

- [JSON Path - Filter Operators](https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath#filter-operators)
- [Advanced Usage of the JSON Path Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter)

---

If response is not valid JSON you will need to go for [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) instead.